# NDepend: Get average LOC per method

Tags: cql, ndepend, cqlinq

Let's say I a have specific method set in my solution. 
How can i get an average number of code lines per method in the method set?

Those numbers are usually shown in the statistic section of each NDepend report (like `Sum, Average, Minimum`, etc) but I want to be able to write queries for such numbers separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQLinq query could be like following:

```
let totalLinesSum = JustMyCode.Methods.Where(t => t.IsPublic).Sum(t => t.NbLinesOfCode)
let methodsCount = JustMyCode.Methods.Where(t => t.IsPublic).Count()

let result = (double)totalLinesSum / methodsCount 

select (double?)result
```

---

...or a bit more refined, this query can be refactored like:

```
// Let define your methods set the way you need
// It is worth removing abstract method that have no LoC
let methodsSet = JustMyCode.Methods.Where(m => m.IsPublic && !m.IsAbstract)

let totalLoc = methodsSet.Sum(t => t.NbLinesOfCode)
let methodsCount = methodsSet.Count()
let avgLoc = (double)totalLoc / methodsCount 

select (double?)avgLoc
```